# batch adding events to google calender

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, android-calendar

Hi I'm trying to add events to a calender with the google-api-java-client and calender API service for a android app. I used the calendersample project created by Yaniv Inbar as a template which works great. When inserting 1 event to the selected calender works perfectly but when i try to batch add events to the calendar get an Illegal state exception.

in the example you could batch add calenders like this.
whole class can be found here [AsyncBatchInsertCalendars.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/android/AsyncBatchInsertCalendars.java?repo=samples)

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {
   BatchRequest batch = client.batch();
   for (Calendar calendar : calendars) {
      client.calendars().insert(calendar).setFields(CalendarInfo.FIELDS)
      .queue(batch, new JsonBatchCallback<Calendar>() {
         public void onSuccess(Calendar calendar, GoogleHeaders headers) {
            model.add(calendar);
         }
         @Override
         public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError err, GoogleHeaders headers)
         throws IOException {
            Utils.logAndShowError(activity, CalendarSampleActivity.TAG, err.getMessage());
         }
      });
   }
   batch.execute();
}
```

I rewrote the class so that it would be events instead of calenders. if you look at the whole class [AsyncBatchInsertEvent.java](http://pastebin.com/epKpvqz7) you'll see that in the doInBackground methode I also loop through a arraylist creating a list of events. which should than be added to the batch to be inserted on the given calendar.

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {
   BatchRequest batch = client.batch();
   for (Event event : events) {
      client.events().insert(calender.id, event).queue(batch, 
      new JsonBatchCallback<Event>() {
         public void onSuccess(Event event, GoogleHeaders headers) {
            //TODO show succes message.
         }
         @Override
         public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError err, GoogleHeaders headers)
         throws IOException {
            Utils.logAndShowError(activity, EventActivity.TAG, err.getMessage());
         }
      });
   }
   batch.execute();
}
```

If I use this then get a an exception and the app crashes

```
W/dalvikvm(21030): threadid=20: thread exiting with 
uncaught exception (group=0x40c19930)
E/AndroidRuntime(21030): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
E/AndroidRuntime(21030): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured 
while executing doInBackground()
```

The full stacktrace of the error can be found here at pastebin [log.txt](http://pastebin.com/YhDVxCdh). Does anyone know how to fix this or did I implement the code incorrectly? the whole code can be found here at pastbin [AsyncBatchInsertEvent.java](http://pastebin.com/epKpvqz7)

Comment: I researched this some more and seems batch.execute(); false cause batch contains 0 queued items. when i run batch.size() the output is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me, the arraylist events was empty cause i checked a string == string instead of string.equels(string).